gspread exceeded api call quota even though I only run it once per minute?
I am using google drive with google colab. Here is the code (basically, login to google drive, read a spreadsheet with some data, process that data, and write it to another spread sheet)
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
import gspread
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from google.auth import default
creds, _ = default()
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)
worksheet = gc.open_by_key('some_key').sheet1
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(worksheet.get_all_records())
aslist = dataframe.values.tolist()

# do some stuff with the data

from pprint import pprint
pprint(gc.list_spreadsheet_files())

sheet = gc.open_by_key('some_other_key')
sheet.values_update(
    'Sheet1!A1',
    params={'valueInputOption': 'RAW'},
    body={'values': newlist}
)

Here is the error:
APIError: {
    'code': 429,
    'message': "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Read requests' and limit 'Read requests per minute' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:some_id'.",
    'status': 'RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED',
    'details': [
        {
            '@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo',
            'reason': 'RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED',
            'domain': 'googleapis.com',
            'metadata': {
                'quota_limit': 'ReadRequestsPerMinutePerProject',
                'quota_location': 'global',
                'consumer': 'projects/some_id',
                'quota_metric': 'sheets.googleapis.com/read_requests',
                'service': 'sheets.googleapis.com',
                'quota_limit_value': '1500'
                }
        }, 
        {
            '@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help',
            'links': [
                {
                    'description': 'Request a higher quota limit.',
                    'url': 'https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#requesting_higher_quota'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

I tried to check my Google Cloud, but I can't even find the project id and the Google Sheets API is not even enabled (and even after I enabled it, there is not information in there)
Edit: not sure where I can find the usage metrics, this is the only thing I saw on google cloud


Not related to your question, but is there a particular reason you're interrupting your imports with code? I've seen that before, but I might just be really green.

Make sure to check your quotas and see exactly what you're getting/posting. I'm not really sure how to answer your question without more information; chances are, the solution is just to stay within the quota even if it's really low.

the code was initially in multiple separate cells in google colab

Projects, in part, group Services. Services are {service}.googleapis.com (e.g. sheets.googleapis.com). The error message's 'consumer': 'projects/some_id' gives you the Project ID (some_id). You can then browse the project's service's quota as: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/sheets.googleapis.com/quotas?project={some_id}

Unfortunately, you don't know how pandas does its importing.  If it does a row at a time, for instance, you'd bump up against a 1500-read limit pretty quickly.
